# How to get CSV Files from S3 and transform to XML using Talend mediation route?

Tags: amazon-s3, talend

I am creating a route for the below scenario.

1. Connect to AWSS3
2. Download CSV files from an S3 bucket and save the file to the directory
3. Read the CSV file from a directory and transform CSV rows into XML

I tried to do the first two-point, but unfortunately, there is no component to close the connection. Also not sure on how to pass the CSV file to cTaldnJob for transformation.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a connection to s3. follow the guide here: https://help.talend.com/reader/3iNwsJWYog7gRV7uP2VB8A/_6EGNH0rljAoVzHZgicP2A
2. get the file downloaded to local environment using ts3get function. follow the guide here: https://help.talend.com/reader/3iNwsJWYog7gRV7uP2VB8A/kJPvw2VLl3o9hIwwDBu12Q
3. Read the CSV file from a directory and transform CSV rows into XML -> there is so many tutorials on the internet on how to do this. time to scout the internet.

hope it helps.